# Examples on spring kafka batch processing with filter strategy and manual commit

Tags: spring-kafka

i am planning to do batch processing using spring kafka batch listener. I am looking for few samples for these 2 scenarios.

1. How do we implement filter record strategy with batch processing?  UPDATE : From the document - " In addition, a FilteringBatchMessageListenerAdapter is provided, for when you use a batch message listener." is not clear.  I did not see any container factory method to set this filterbatchmessagelisteneradapter object or filter implementation.

HERE is my code for batch listener filter strategy :

```
@Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<?, ?> kafkaListenerContainerFactory(
            ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer,
            ConsumerFactory<Object, Object> kafkaConsumerFactory) {

        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Object, Object> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Object, Object>();
        configurer.configure(factory, kafkaConsumerFactory);
        factory.setBatchListener(true);
        factory.setAckDiscarded(true);
        factory.setRecordFilterStrategy(new RecordFilterStrategy<Object, Object>() {
            @Override
            public boolean filter(ConsumerRecord<Object, Object> consumerRecords) {

                //log.info("Retrieved the record {} from the partition {} with offset {}", consumerRecord.value(), consumerRecord.partition(), consumerRecord.offset());

                return true;
            }
        });
        
        return factory;
    }
```

2. How can we do a manual  offset commit,  once we retrieve the batch of messages in the consumer and all got processed.  During batch process if any failure comes, just want to push that  message to error topic.But finally I would like to commit entire batch at a time .

Now other question I came to mind is how the above scenario works with a single consumer  and with multiple consumers.

Let’s say case 1 : single consumer

Let’s say we have a topic with 5 partitions . When we subscribe to  that topic, we assume we got 100 messages from the topic in which each partition has 20 messages. If we want to commit these message offset, does the acknowledgment object hold each partition and last offset of the last message?

Case2: multiple consumers

With the same input as mentioned in case1, If we enable the equal no of consumers with partition count,  does the ack object hold partition and last message offset?

Can you please help me on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. See `FilteringBatchMessageListenerAdapter` https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#filtering-messages
2. The simplest way to do handle exceptions with a batch is to use a `RecoveringBatchErrorHandler` with a `DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer`. Throw a `BatchListenerFailedException` to indicate which record in the batch failed; the offsets for the successful records are committed and the remaining records (including the failed one) will be redelivered until retries (if configured) are exhausted, when the failed record will go to the dead letter topic and the rest will be redelivered.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#recovering-batch-eh

Yes, when the batch is acknowledged, the latest offset (+1) for each partition in the batch is committed.

If you have multiple consumers, the partitions are distributed across those consumers.

Comment: Thanks Gary for your response. I have modified 2 question.     For the filter strategy can you provide sample code how to implement  the filteringbatchmessagelisteneradapter? I did not see any container factory method to set this filterbatchmessagelisteneradapter object .

Comment: Just add a filter strategy to the container factory `containerFactory.setRecordFilterStrategy()`; the framework will wire in the filtering adapter configured with that strategy.

Comment: would this take care of filter batch criteria?

        factory.setBatchListener(true);
        factory.setAckDiscarded(true);
        factory.setRecordFilterStrategy(new RecordFilterStrategy<Object, Object>() {
            @Override
            public boolean filter(ConsumerRecord<Object, Object> consumerRecord) {

                //log.info("Apply filter criteria on the record {} ", consumerRecord.val());
                return true;
            }
        });

Comment: Yes; that is correct. Don't put code in comments; it's too hard to read; edit the question instead and comment that you have done so.

Comment: i have doubt that how the container knows whether it is filtering batch of records or a single record  and internally uses the filterbatchmessagelisteneradapter  object?  is it based on   factory.setBatchListener(true); factory.setAckDiscarded(true); values ?

Comment: Yes, the framework decides which adapter to apply. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/blob/f633c44ecc5851a6966a11c58d1a0429fb4c7a13/spring-kafka/src/main/java/org/springframework/kafka/config/AbstractKafkaListenerEndpoint.java#L516-L531

Comment: Thanks @Gary..  on first question.. Appreciate your help!!   Can you please answer the second question too ?

Comment: Thank you so much @Gary on timely input.. I understood the concept cleary. Thanks